# networkD3 (Sankey) and sunburstR (Sanburst) package can not be useed together in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, sankey-diagram, sunburst-diagram, networkd3

I'm trying to include a senkey diagram (networkD3) and a sunburst diagram  (sunburstR) into a Shiny app, but I find it did not work when I put them together. I don't get any errors however only the Sankey diagram displayed. Does anyone had the same experience?

I would really appreciate any help you can give.

Here is the R code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library("sunburstR")
library("D3partitionR")
library("networkD3")
library("visNetwork")
```

**ui.R**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
tabItem(tabName = "Sunburst",
        fluidPage(
          fluidRow(
            sunburstOutput("sunburst")
          )
        ),

        tabItem(tabName = "Sankey",
                fluidPage(
                  fluidRow(
                    sankeyNetworkOutput("sankey")
                  )
                )
            )
      )
)
```

**server.R**

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$sunburst <- renderSunburst({
    add_shiny(sunburst(sequence))

    })


    output$sankey <- renderSankeyNetwork({
    invalidateLater(100, session)
    sankeyNetwork(Links = Links, Nodes = Nodes,
                 Source = "Source2", Target = "Target2",
                 Value = "Value", NodeID = "name",
                 colourScale = JS("d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);")
                 )
  })
 }
```

Comment: pls provide a fully reproducible example, incl. `Links`, `Nodes` etc.

Comment: The cause of the problem is that networkD3 has been updated to D3v4 and sunburstR is still using D3v3. I don't know of anyway to work around it on the user side. Actually, the only solution I can think of that you can currently do is downgrade networkD3 to a version <0.3, which is when we upgraded it to D3v4.

Answer (score 1):

The currently available, [v1.0.0 version of `sunburstR` (published 2017-06-13)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sunburstR/index.html) uses D3v4 and should not conflict with networkD3. Try updating your packages.